# Python outlook sent items folder data extraction( using MAPI and pywin32)

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, pywin32

Here I am trying to extract one particular email data which is present in sent items folder in outlook?
but I am unable to find any method to give such condition , like if this particular email present in sent item folder then extract subject, date & time.

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch

import  regex as re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

sentitem = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(5)
messages = sentitem.Items


for msg in messages:
```

here after I am not getting any idea.
Can anyone help me to find this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use regex with the Outlook Object Model, but you can use `Items.Find/FindNext` and `Items.Restrict` to find the message(s).

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict for the syntax and sample queries.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all items and checking item's properties is not really a good idea when dealing with the Outlook object model:

```
for msg in messages
```

Instead, the OOM provides three main ways for getting the job done:

1. Use the `Find`/`FindNext` methods of the `Items` class. See [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/) for more information.
2. Use the `Restrict` method of the `Items` class. This method is an alternative to using the `Find` method or `FindNext` method to iterate over specific items within a collection. The `Find` or `FindNext` methods are faster than filtering if there are a small number of items. The `Restrict` method is significantly faster if there is a large number of items in the collection, especially if only a few items in a large collection are expected to be found. See [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/) for more information.
3. The `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class. The key benefits of using the AdvancedSearch method in Outlook are:

   - The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
   - Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
   - Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
   - You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

   Read more about the `AdvancedSearch` method in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.